# How to manage configuration files on multiple branches in Git?

Tags: github, configuration-files

Considering a very basic scenario, in Git I have 3 branches, development, staging, and production.  I am checking in a particular webserver configuration, that has something hardcoded per environment.  For example,  I have a nginx.conf file, that has a hardcoded URL in it, depending on what environment I am building.

- Such as in development branch in nginx.conf, I have www.dev.mywebsite.com
- In staging I have www.staging.mywebsite.com
- and in production I have www.mywebsite.com

If I make an update to the configuration file in dev, I have to manually copy/paste all my changes and diff the file between newly modified dev, and another branch.

What is the best right, or just the easiest way of managing multiple configuration files, so I don't have to manually copy/paste in Github?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to copy/paste. You only need to merge.

For example:

In branch **dev:**

**nginx.conf**

```
server = www.dev.mywebsite.com
```

In branch **staging:**

**nginx.conf**

```
server = www.staging.mywebsite.com
```

In branch **production:**

**nginx.conf**

```
server = www.mywebsite.com
```

you add a line in dev:

**nginx.conf**

```
server = www.dev.mywebsite.com
newconf=new1
```

and commit as commit-1

then you can just switch to the other two branch and merge from dev:
the the other two will look like:
In branch **staging:**

**nginx.conf**

```
server = www.staging.mywebsite.com
newconf=new1
```

In branch **production:**

**nginx.conf**

```
server = www.mywebsite.com
newconf=new1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider versioning separate configuration files for each of the three branches, e.g. `nginx_dev.conf`, `nginx_stage.conf`, and `nginx_prod.conf`.  As you work in each branch, you would update only the configuration file for that branch.  Of course, the configuration file you would use when actually building is `nginx.conf`, so you would have to copy over from one of the branch files.

While this does not completely solve your problem, it would at least relieve you from having manually edit the `nginx.conf` file across branch changes.